# http.put: "404 not found" in ionic 2

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic2

I am trying to update some data in my API using http.put but I always get "404 not found". Here is my code:

TS file:

```
activate(customer) {

if(this.mycode==this.cuscode) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body = JSON.stringify(customer);

  this.http.put('http://myApi.com/customer/' + this.id, body, options )
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Successfully Activated your Account.");
  }, (err) => {
      console.log("ERROR: " +err);
  });
}else {
  this.wrongcode = true;
  console.log("NOT ACTIVATED! Incorrect code mate.");
}
```

}

HTML file:

```
<ion-item [(ngModel)]="mycode">
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Activation Code" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
    <button ion-button (click)="activate(customer)"><ion-icon name="check"></ion-icon>Activate Now</button>
```

I get this error:

```
 PUT http://myApi/customer/72 404 (Not Found)
```

My API is working fine but I do not know why is it not found? Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you check from the server if your api method has "put"  instead of "get". Also try hitting this from advance rest client or any other rest client.

Comment: thank you for the response, but what do you mean by check from the server?

Comment: Try to use network tab in your devtools, check your this.mycode and this.cucode via console.log

Comment: @DmitryGrinko, the if condition works and this.mycode and cuscode is the code typed and the verification code. thank you for the response.

Comment: I had run into the same problem once, API was exposed as "get" so when I try hitting this from the browser it used to send me the result but "put" method was not exposed, for an example if this is the nodejs api code should be like this 

expressRoute.put('/your/put/route', function(res,req){...}),

in my case it was exposed as expressRoute.get('/your/put/route',...), so just confirm from the back end team and see if it is exposed in the correct manner.

Comment: Did you use tab networks of devtools? What is your error?

Comment: it just the same in the console which is 404 sir

Comment: First of all add error handler for you server code.

Comment: have you checked if it server has provided the get method for that url or put is also there. You can also try to run Http option for that url and see if get is allowed or not.

Comment: i have tried the get and post, it worked for me.

Comment: you were looking for put or post?

Comment: i am looking for put

Comment: then try put, or check with my answer, your api must return "put" when tried dto reach with Http Options

Answer (score 0):

try seeing the options like this from advance rest client, if you have a put method exposed it will show "put" for that url in advanced rest client

[image: it must also return out for you]

Comment: thank you, how can I see it from advance rest client? sorry im a newbie.

Comment: its a chrome extension go to the webapps and from chrome and add one. after that opthe ARC(Advance rest client) and then key in your URL the way I have written for "http://localhost:8080/dev/putNames" select the options from method dropdown, and then click send. It will show you all the methods exposed to that URL

Comment: I already did it, It shows "access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH

Comment: Then check if you are forming the url correctly in your angular service. Try hitting the url with put request and parameters which is id in your case that will give you correct error information

Comment: I already did that and the error says "PUT 404 url not found".